# POST request in angular returns status -1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, post

I need help submitting a POST request using angularjs because I keep receiving an error callback of -1 (and the sent data is always null, except for when I look in response.config.data). I tried using both shorthand/longhand, urlencoded and application/json to no avail.

Here is the code I use for the longhand/url encoded attempt:

```
                 // data to send to muscle
                 var content = {
                      email: "...",
                      title: "...",
                      format: "...",
                      tree: "...",
                      order: "...",
                      sequence: data.join()
                 };

                 $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/services/rest/muscle/run/',
                    data: content,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'
                    },
                    transformRequest: [function(data) {
                                return angular.isObject(data) && String(data) !== '[object File]' ? $httpParamSerializer(data) : data;
                        }]

                     }).then (function successCallback(response) {
                        console.log("SUCCESS");
                     }, function errorCallback(response) {
                        console.log("ERROR");
                        console.log(response);
                        console.log(response.headers);
                        console.log(response.config);

                     });
```

Here is the code I use for my shorthand/json attempt

```
    // submit post to MUSCLE
    $http.post('http://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/services/rest/muscle/run/', content).then(function (success) { ....
```

Here is the error I receive in both cases:

```
Object { data: null, status: -1, headers: fd/<(), config: Object, statusText: "" }
Object { method: "POST", transformRequest: Array[1], transformResponse: Array[1], paramSerializer: nf/this.$get/<(), url: "http://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/services…", data: Object, headers: Object }
```

Here is the reference [website](http://www.ebi.ac.uk/Tools/webservices/services/msa/muscle_rest) I am using to submit the POST (The Run request)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!